# itoa using reverse(string) code showing error

Tags: c, itoa

Why doesn't ANSI C use `strrev` instead of creating such a big reverse function?

This code is showing me an error. Please correct it. What is the error. I am using Code::Blocks

Error message that I get:

> c:\programfiles(x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1......\libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7)||undefined reference to `WinMain@16'|

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

 void reverse(int n, char s[])
 {
     int c,i, j;

     for(i=0, j= strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--){
         c=s[i];
         s[i]=s[j];
         s[j]=c;
     }
  }

 void itoa(int n, char s[])
 {
     int i=0 ,sign;

     if((sign=n) < 0 )
         n= -n;
     do{
         s[i++] = n%10 + '0';
     }while(n /=10 >0);

     if(sign <0)
         s[i++] = '-';

     s[i] = '\0';
     reverse(n, s);
 }
```

Comment: Because nobody needs to reverse a string, except for homework, and implementing itoa.

Comment: `n= -n;` is undefined behavior for 2's complement architectures when `n` is `INT_MIN`. Proper `itoa` implementations do not do this.

Comment: @MooingDuck ok so that means i have to be using strrev in ordinary conditions?

Comment: @PascalCuoq i have copy pasted this code from ANSI C book this n=-n is correct. The problem was i didn't added main function.

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan: No, he's correct, `n = -n` will fail if `n` is `INT_MIN`. The code has a bug.

Comment: @MooingDuck that means the book has an error sorry for doubting Pascal :)

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan: It's actually quite common.  Doing it without a bug is hard and complicated, so the books just show the simple version for teaching purposes, even though real code should be far more complex.

Comment: @MooingDuck so how should i learn. I learnt from youtube videos & now i am reading ANSI C book....i want to be good programmer :) who writes clean & readable codes excluding bugs

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan: We recommend books from this list for C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list But even if your only book has some bugs, read it.  It will teach you the language at least.  After that, answer questions on StackOverflow.  Commenters will notify you of all bugs you didn't know about.

Comment: @MooingDuck but i am studying C right now from this book: http://www.amazon.in/The-Programming-Language-Ansi-Version/dp/8120305965?tag=googinhydr2112-21

Comment: @MooingDuck i have one more question related to this code why is using s[i] = '\0' at the end shouldn't he use s[i++]= '\0' cause the last value of i has been incremented in while loop if we exclude the if condition after the while loop

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan: That was actually the _best_ book.... 24 years ago.  It's a wee bit out-of-date nowdays.  As for `s[i]` vs `s[i++]`, it depends on what you do with `i` after that.  Since the code doesn't do anything, it doesn't matter what `i` is after the call.  `i++` uses the current value of `i`, and increments `i` _afterwards_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no entry point.  You need to have a `main` function, or `WinMain` or something.

http://mingw-starter.blogspot.com/2008/02/mingw-sdl.html says

> Also, don't forget to add the -mwindows flag, if your IDE doesn't add it automatically (in addition to whatever other libraries you want to link). If you don't put them in the right order, you'll get a linker error complaining about the missing symbol WinMain@16.

Comment: ohh sorry that was so stupid of me didn't pay attention though....really sorry

Comment: it worked i just added 

main(){ return 0;} ....without even using any of these functions

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan: Presumably it "worked" in the sense that it compiled and linked. With `main() { return 0; }` (NOTE: `main()` should be `int main(void)`) the program won't do anything.

Comment: got it @KeithThompson runs without any error now